# Link to apps page on FB

Tags: facebook

Link to my apps page on FB is like this http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=112233445566778899.

But for some apps i saw that link to their pages are like this http://www.facebook.com/AppName. For example: to go to page of app MafiaWars we can use www.facebook.com/MafiaWars...

How can i do like this for my app?? is there any config or what??

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting on Facebook Page called as "username" which will set the link to your FB page as facebook.com/UserName

it can be found under the settings:

```
Edit Profile >> Basic Information >> Username
```